# rich:inplaceSelect not working in RF4

Tags: richfaces

i have a problem with the jsf 2.0 version with inplace select,
in jsf 1.2 it was working, but in jsf 2.0 it is not

problem: when select one of the item in inplace select dropdown, 
I am trying to update it with the selected value using the a4j:ajax tag, using  but the control is not calling the update() method

```
<rich:column id = "locationClmn">
    <f:facet name = "header">
        <h:outputText id = "LocationHeder" styleClass = "headerText"
                        value = "#{messagesRefdata['notifications.locations']}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <c:set var = "locations" value = "#{notificationConfigurationBean.listOfLocations(ntc.notification)}"/>
    <rich:inplaceSelect value = "#{ntc.location}" showControls = "true" 
                        onviewactivation = "old=event.memo.oldValue" rendered="#{locations}">
        <f:selectItems value = "#{notificationConfigurationBean.listOfLocations(ntc.notification)}"/>
            <a4j:ajax action = "#{notificationConfigurationBean.update(ntc)}"
                      ajaxSingle = "true" event = "onviewactivated"
                      onsubmit = "if (event.memo.value == old) {return false;}"
                      render = "notificationsModelPanel">
                <f:param name = "partyId" value = "#{param['partyId']}"/>
             </a4j:ajax>
    </rich:inplaceSelect>
</rich:column>
```

I have even tried f:ajax, execute= "@this", immediate = true, but no luck nothing have worked for me.
can some one help me on this how it could work ???

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onviewactivated` in RichFaces 4, use `onchange` instead. Note that when you're passing the event name it's without the "on", e.g.

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" …>
```

Comment: Hi Makhiel, I have tried change event even then that is not working, onemor thing when i use showControls = "true"  the buttons are displaying and disappearing when we change the value from selection. the update method is not getting called.